# PostgreSQL 9.5: Skip first two lines in the text file

Tags: postgresql

I have the text file to import with the following format:

```
columA    | columnB    |    columnC
-----------------------------------------
1     |     A          |    XYZ
2     |     B          |    XZ
3     |     C          |    YZ
```

I can skip first line by using:

```
WITH CSV HEADER;
```

in copy command, but got stuck while skipping second line.

Comment: `COPY FROM 'file'`, or `COPY FROM STDIN`?

Comment: @NickBarnes, `COPY FROM file`. Here is what i am using `COPY data_table FROM 'X:\File.txt' with delimiter '|' CSV HEADER;
`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `COPY FROM 'filename'`, you could instead use `COPY FROM PROGRAM` to invoke some shell command which removes the header from the file and returns the rest.

In Windows:

```
COPY t FROM PROGRAM 'more +2 "C:\Path\To\File.txt"'
```

In Linux:

```
COPY t FROM PROGRAM 'tail -n +3 /path/to/file.txt'
```

If you're trying to send a local file to a remote server, you can do something similar through `psql`, e.g.:

```
tail -n +3 file.txt | psql -c 'COPY t FROM STDIN'
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much.

Comment: This only works when the server can directly access the file. In case the file resides on another computer (i.e. a client accessing the server through psql or a library/framework), this won't work.

Comment: @Patrick: Thanks, definitely worth mentioning. I've added a client-side psql example. If you're running `COPY FROM STDIN` through a client library, you can probably just set the stream position yourself before passing it in.

Comment: @Patrick is there documentation on using 'tail' in psql? New to programs in sql.

Comment: @thleo: `tail` has nothing to do with `psql`; it's a [Linux utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `COPY` command can only skip the first line. The easiest solution would be to manually remove the second line before importing but if that is not possible, then you have to use a "dirty" trick.

You create a table that has a single column of `varchar` type and import the text file into that table. After import you run a PL/pgSQL function to read all the rows in the table (except the header rows, obviously) and extract the information you want to insert in the destination table with, for instance, the `regexp_matches()` or `regexp_split_to_array()` function. You can also automate the whole process by using an after insert trigger on the import table, if you have to import many files with the same issue.